# How to annotate a Django QuerySet aggregating annotated Subquery

Tags: python, django, aggregate, django-orm, annotate

I have a few Django models with a FK relationship between them:

```py
from django.db import models


class Order(models.Model):
    notes = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)


class OrderLine(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, blank=True, decimal_places=2)
```

Given an `OrderLine` you can calculate its total as quantity by price:

```py
def get_order_line_total(order_line):
    return order_line.quantity * order_line.price
```

Given an `Order` you can calculate its total as the sum of its order lines totals:

```py
def get_order_total(order):
    order_total = 0
    for orderline_for in order.orderline_set.all():
        order_total += (order_line_for.quantity * order_line_for.price)
    return order_total
```

I want to annotate that totals in querysets so I can filtrate them, sort them, etc.

For the `OrderLine` models I found it pretty straight forward:

```py
from django.db.models import F, FloatField, Sum


annotated_orderline_set = OrderLine.objects.annotate(orderline_total=Sum(F('quantity') * F('price'), output_field=FloatField()))
```

Now I want to annotate the total in an `Order.objects` queryset. I guess I would need to use a Subquery but I can't make it work.
My guess is (Not working):

```py
from django.db.models import F, FloatField, OuterRef, Subquery, Sum


Order.objects.annotate(
    order_total=Subquery(
        OrderLine.objects.filter(
            order=OuterRef('pk')
        ).annotate(
            orderline_total=Sum(F('quantity') * F('price'), output_field=FloatField())
        ).values(
            'orderline_total'
        ).aggregate(
            Sum('orderline_total')
        )['orderline_total__sum']
    )
)

# Not working, returns:
# ValueError: This queryset contains a reference to an outer query and may only be used in a subquery.
```

How could I solve this?

Comment: Order.objects.annotate(orderline_total=Sum(F('orderline__quantity')*F('orderline__price'), output_field=FloatField()))

Comment: @aedry Your comment solved my problem, it's simpler than I imagined. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @aedry comment pointed out, a very simple solution avoiding the Subquery is:

```py
Order.objects.annotate(total=models.Sum(F('orderline_set__quantity') * F('orderline_set__price'), output_field=models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)))
```

(I applied the `output_field=DecimalField` idea from @Todor answer for type consistency)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `.aggregate` because this evaluates the `queryset` immediately while you need this evaluation to be delayed until the outer query is being evaluated.

So the correct approach is to `.annotate` instead of `.aggregate`.

```
class OrderQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def annotate_total(self):
        return self.annotate(
            total=models.Subquery(
                OrderLine.objects.filter(
                    order=models.OuterRef('pk')
                ).annotate_total()
                .values('order')
                .annotate(total_sum=models.Sum('total'))
                .values('total_sum')
            )
        )


class Order(models.Model):
    # ...
    objects = OrderQuerySet.as_manager()


class OrderLineQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def annotate_total(self):
        return self.annotate(
            total=models.ExpressionWrapper(
                models.F('quantity')*models.F('price'),
                output_field=models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
            )
        )


class OrderLine(models.Model):
    #...
    objects = OrderLineQuerySet.as_manager()


# Usage:
>>> for l in OrderLine.objects.all().annotate_total():
...    print(l.id, l.order_id, l.quantity, l.price, l.total)
... 
1 1 3 20.00 60
2 1 9 10.00 90
3 2 18 2.00 36

>>> for o in Order.objects.all().annotate_total():
...    print(o.id, o.total)
... 
1 150
2 36
```

Comment: I tried your code and usage for OrderLine.objects.all().annotate_total() is working OK but for Order.objects.all().annotate_total() usage I'm getting `KeyError: 'total'` for Django 2.0.7 and `ProgrammingError: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression` for Django 2.1.7. Did you get it working? What Django version did you use? Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: This error in not related to the version of Django. Its either `data` or `queryset` related, you can inspect the generated query with `print(queryset.query)` and debug why you get multiple rows for a subquery, any change you are missing the first `.values('order')` which will group by `order`?

Comment: Nop, I copied the code in your answer, did you get it working? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, I have it working on a test project with 2 orders and 3 OrderLine's as you can see from the example usage. Again, debug your subquery, run it manually and you will see why you get multiple rows for a subquery.

Comment: Hey @Todor, thank you very much for your follow up. I make a super simple app with the minimum code required and it worked. After a little research I found that using Postgres is when your code throws "KeyError: 'total'".